# How do you download object from AWS S3 bucket using AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 client side encryption?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We were using AmazonS3EncryptionClient in our code to interact with S3 bucket using client side encryption. But on updating nuget package today, I noticed that AmazonS3EncryptionClient has been marked obsolete. Looks like we will need to use AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 if we want to get continuous update going forward. I am having this issue while trying to migrate from AmazonS3EncryptionClient to AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2.

In our old code we were using AmazonS3EncryptionClient constructor that takes RegionEnpoint as a parameter. see image below. Looks like constructors that takes RegionEnpoint has been removed in AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2.

[image: AmazonS3EncryptionClient]

Old code that was working to GetObject from S3 bucket.

```
S3BucketConfiguration _s3BucketConfiguration = provider
   .GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<S3BucketConfiguration>>()
   .Value;

var credential = new BasicAWSCredentials(
    _s3BucketConfiguration.AccessKey, _s3BucketConfiguration.SecurityKey);

RegionEndpoint bucketRegion =
    RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_s3BucketConfiguration.Region);

EncryptionMaterials encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterials(_s3BucketConfiguration.KMSKeyId);

var client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(credential, bucketRegion, encryptionMaterials);

GetObjectResponse response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = _s3BucketConfig.BucketName,
    Key = filePath
});
```

I cannot pass in RegionEnpoint in AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2.

[image: No constructor to pass in region endpoint in AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2]

My Code so far.

```
S3BucketConfiguration _s3BucketConfiguration = provider
   .GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<S3BucketConfiguration>>()
   .Value;

var credential = new BasicAWSCredentials(
    _s3BucketConfiguration.AccessKey, _s3BucketConfiguration.SecurityKey);

RegionEndpoint bucketRegion =
    RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_s3BucketConfiguration.Region);

var encryptionMaterials = new EncryptionMaterialsV2(
    _s3BucketConfiguration.KMSKeyId, 
    KmsType.KmsContext, 
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
);

var config = new AmazonS3CryptoConfigurationV2(SecurityProfile.V2AndLegacy);

//If I add this line it will instantiate AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 but, the GetObject call fails.
//If I do not add this line, it will give me same error while instiantiating AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2
//config.RegionEndpoint = bucketRegion; 

vr client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2(credential, config, encryptionMaterials);

GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = _s3BucketConfig.BucketName,
    Key = filePath,
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Exception

```
No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured
```

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully encrypt with V1 and decrypt with V2 client along with passing the `RegionEndpoint`.

```
var configuration = new AmazonS3CryptoConfiguration()
{
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2
};
var material = new EncryptionMaterials(KmsKeyId);
var client = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(configuration, material);

var putObjectResponse = await client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest()
{
    ContentBody = ContentBody,
    BucketName = Bucket,
    Key = Key
});

if (putObjectResponse.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var configurationV2 = new AmazonS3CryptoConfigurationV2(SecurityProfile.V2AndLegacy)
    {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2
    };
    var materialV2 = new EncryptionMaterialsV2(KmsKeyId, KmsType.KmsContext, new Dictionary<string, string>());
    var clientV2 = new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2(configurationV2, materialV2);

    var getObjectResponse = await clientV2.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = Bucket,
        Key = Key
    });

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Can you make sure you are using the same `RegionEndpoint` during the encryption and decryption?

Comment: Thank for the reply. I tried your code out however I used another constructor for AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 that takes credentials. It did not work. Getting same error. 

https://imgur.com/a/GUGtV31

Comment: Also, how do you use the AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2 without passing credentials? I mean how does sdk know where to get the access key and secret from?

Comment: If you have [stored credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) in credential file, SDK will automatically take them by default.

The issue doesn't seem be related with credential though. Are you able to save and retrieve a new object? Similar to what I'm doing in the provided code snippet.

Comment: Sorry I was busy last few days. Could not look into this. When I use your code I am getting the same error but while calling PutObjectAsync method. I feel like this might have something to do with the stored credentials. I tried using stored credentials it works for AmazonS3Client(without client side encryption) but when switch to client I get this error.